# Problem in uninstalling visual studio 2010 professional

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, ide, uninstallation

I have Visual Studio 2010 Professional, i just got new Ultimate edition of Visual Studio 2010. I'm trying to uninstall the previous Professional version but it isn't working

- When i try uninstalling through control panel it just freezes on
  **generating setup script** and after few times Operating becomes not
  responding, i waited for an hour but it didn't worked
- Then i downloaded the Microsoft Utlity **Visual Studio 2010
  Uninstall Utility** and that also didn't worked for me, it again
  stuck in the middle of the progress bar with no reason

Can anyone tell me if he has any idea whats going on and how i can uninstall it

Comment: I've always had a mixed experience uninstalling VS 2010.  Whenever I can't get it to uninstall properly I've had to backup my files and reformat.

Comment: Well there must be any other solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to uninstall VS2010 Pro to upgrade to Ultimate. Just run the Ultimate installer without doing anything to your existing VS2010 Pro installation and your version will be upgraded.

Comment: Okay thanks, i installed Ultimate on Pro version. Its upgraded now